# Elasticsearch, ordering aggregations by geo distance and score

Tags: elasticsearch, distance, aggregation

My mapping is the following:

```
PUT places
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "id_product": { "type": "keyword" },
        "id_product_unique": { "type": "integer" },
        "location": { "type": "geo_point" },
        "suggest": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "active": {"type": "boolean"}
      }
    }
  }
}

POST places/test
{
   "id_product" : "A",
   "id_product_unique": 1,
   "location": {
      "lat": 1.378446,
      "lon": 103.763427
   },
   "suggest": ["coke","zero"],
   "active": true
}

POST places/test
{
   "id_product" : "A",
   "id_product_unique": 2,
   "location": {
      "lat": 1.878446,
      "lon": 108.763427
   },
   "suggest": ["coke","zero"],
   "active": true
}

POST places/test
{
   "id_product" : "B",
   "id_product_unique": 3,
   "location": {
      "lat": 1.478446,
      "lon": 104.763427
   },
   "suggest": ["coke"],
   "active": true
}

POST places/test
{
   "id_product" : "C",
   "id_product_unique": 4,
   "location": {
      "lat": 1.218446,
      "lon": 102.763427
   },
   "suggest": ["coke","light"],
   "active": true
}
```

In my example there is 2 can of coke zero (`"id_product_unique" = 1` and `2`), 1 can of coke (`"id_product_unique" = 3`) and one can of coke light (`"id_product_unique" = 4`)

All these cans are in different locations.

An "`id_product`" is not unique as an exact same "can of coke" can be sold in two different locations (ex `"id_product_unique" = 1` and `2`).

Only "`id_product_unique`" and "location" change from a "can of coke" to an other one (2 same "can of coke" have the same fields "suggest" and "`id_product`" but not the same "`id_product_unique`" and "`location`").

My goal is to search for a product from a given GPS location, and display a unique result by id_product (the closest one):

```
POST /places/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs" : {
    "group-by-type" : {
      "terms" : { "field" : "id_product"},
      "aggs": {
        "min-distance": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": {
              "_script": { 
                "type": "number",
                "script": {
                  "source": "def x = doc['location'].lat; def y = doc['location'].lon; return Math.abs(x-1.178446) + Math.abs(y-101.763427)",
                  "lang": "painless"
                },
                "order": "asc"
              }
            },
            "size" : 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

From this list of result I'd like now to apply a should query and to re-order my list of result by computed score. I tried the following:

```
POST /places/_search?size=0
{
  "query" : {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {"term" : { "active" : "true" }},
      "should": [
        {"match" : { "suggest" : "coke" }},
        {"match" : { "suggest" : "light" }}
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs" : {
    "group-by-type" : {
      "terms" : { "field" : "id_product"},
      "aggs": {
        "min-distance": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": {
              "_script": { 
                "type": "number",
                "script": {
                  "source": "def x = doc['location'].lat; def y = doc['location'].lon; return Math.abs(x-1.178446) + Math.abs(y-101.763427)",
                  "lang": "painless"
                },
                "order": "asc"
              }
            },
            "size" : 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I cannot figure how to replace the distance sort score by the doc score.

Any help would be great.

Comment: What version of ES do you have?

Comment: I'm using version 6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it by adding a new aggregation "max_score":

```
"max_score": {
  "max": {
    "script": {
      "lang": "painless",
      "source": "_score"
    }
  }
}
```

and by ordering by max_score.value desc:

```
"order": {"max_score.value": "desc"}
```

My final query is the following:

```
POST /places/_search?size=0
{
  "query" : {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {"term" : { "active" : "true" }},
      "should": [
        {"match" : { "suggest" : "coke" }},
        {"match" : { "suggest" : "light" }}
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs" : {
    "group-by-type" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "id_product",
          "order": {"max_score.value": "desc"}
      },
      "aggs": {
        "min-distance": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": {
              "_script": { 
                "type": "number",
                "script": {
                  "source": "def x = doc['location'].lat; def y = doc['location'].lon; return Math.abs(x-1.178446) + Math.abs(y-101.763427)",
                  "lang": "painless"
                },
                "order": "asc"
              }
            },
            "size" : 1
          }
        },
        "max_score": {
          "max": {
            "script": {
              "lang": "painless",
              "inline": "_score"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

answer:

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "group-by-type": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "C",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "max_score": {
            "value": 1.0300811529159546
          },
          "min-distance": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 1,
              "max_score": null,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "places",
                  "_type": "test",
                  "_id": "VhJdOmIBKhzTB9xcDvfk",
                  "_score": null,
                  "_source": {
                    "id_product": "C",
                    "id_product_unique": 4,
                    "location": {
                      "lat": 1.218446,
                      "lon": 102.763427
                    },
                    "suggest": [
                      "coke",
                      "light"
                    ],
                    "active": true
                  },
                  "sort": [
                    1.0399999646503995
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "A",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "max_score": {
            "value": 0.28768208622932434
          },
          "min-distance": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 2,
              "max_score": null,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "places",
                  "_type": "test",
                  "_id": "UhJcOmIBKhzTB9xc6ve-",
                  "_score": null,
                  "_source": {
                    "id_product": "A",
                    "id_product_unique": 1,
                    "location": {
                      "lat": 1.378446,
                      "lon": 103.763427
                    },
                    "suggest": [
                      "coke",
                      "zero"
                    ],
                    "active": true
                  },
                  "sort": [
                    2.1999999592114756
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "B",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "max_score": {
            "value": 0.1596570909023285
          },
          "min-distance": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 1,
              "max_score": null,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "places",
                  "_type": "test",
                  "_id": "VRJcOmIBKhzTB9xc_vc0",
                  "_score": null,
                  "_source": {
                    "id_product": "B",
                    "id_product_unique": 3,
                    "location": {
                      "lat": 1.478446,
                      "lon": 104.763427
                    },
                    "suggest": [
                      "coke"
                    ],
                    "active": true
                  },
                  "sort": [
                    3.2999999020282695
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I gathered, your use case is where you want to factor in the value of a particular field in your document into the calculation of the relevance score. 
This is typical in scenarios where you want the boost the relevance of a document based on a value of a field, like a price or here a query for a particular product.
If you are searching for produt A, that is more important in this scenario than the distance of the products themselves.  So if B is 2 miles away from origin and A is 5 miles, A is the closest of the product you are searching for.

What you need is a Function Score Query using a decay_function based on the distance.  I think you want a gauss type to reflect the rate of decay, which operates like a bell curve.

Here is an example using a decay function of the exp (exponent) type.  This use case is doing the same thing, but it is using a different field type (date) than
you are, but the idea should be the same.

> Suppose that instead of wanting to boost incrementally by the value of
>   a field, you have an ideal value you want to target and you want the
>   boost factor to decay the further away you move from the value. This
>   is typically useful in boosts based on lat/long, numeric fields like
>   price, or dates. In our contrived example, we are searching for books
>   on “search engines” ideally published around June 2014.

```
POST /bookdb_index/book/_search
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "multi_match" : {
                    "query" : "search engine",
                    "fields": ["title", "summary"]
                }
            },
            "functions": [
                {
                    "exp": {
                        "publish_date" : {
                            "origin": "2014-06-15",
                            "offset": "7d",
                            "scale" : "30d"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "boost_mode" : "replace"
        }
    },
    "_source": ["title", "summary", "publish_date", "num_reviews"]
}
```

Here are some useful references for this:

[Elasticsearch 6.2 Function Score document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/query-dsl-function-score-query.html)

[Elastcisearch Example Queries](https://dzone.com/articles/23-useful-elasticsearch-example-queries)

[The Closer the Better](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/decay-functions.html)
This is an Elasticsearch 2x Decay Function example  and even though it's a different version, I think it is very similar to your use case